# Encoding single quote with node

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

We are using cloudfront to cache our resource. When we have to invalidate cache, we are making request to cloudfront API to invalidate cache where we need to send URL to invalidate. Due to single quote in URL, cloudfront is throwing us error of invalidation path error.

Our URL is /autocomplete/posts/2?term=13 Scary Podcasts That'll Keep You Up All Night&pagesize=25&pagenumber=1&excludeexpiredposts=true

We are using encodeURI(url) which give us following

"/autocomplete/posts/2?term=13%20Scary%20Podcasts%20That'll%20Keep%20You%20Up%20All%20Night&pagesize=25&pagenumber=1&excludeexpiredposts=true" - Not valid for CloudFront

If we use encodeURIComponent, it give us following
"%2Fautocomplete%2Fposts%2F2%3Fterm%3D13%20Scary%20Podcasts%20That'll%20Keep%20You%20Up%20All%20Night%26pagesize%3D25%26pagenumber%3D1%26excludeexpiredposts%3Dtrue" - Not valid for Cloudfront

If we use escape, it gives us following;
"/autocomplete/posts/2%3Fterm%3D13%20Scary%20Podcasts%20That%27ll%20Keep%20You%20Up%20All%20Night%26pagesize%3D25%26pagenumber%3D1%26excludeexpiredposts%3Dtrue" - VALID FOR CLOUDFRONT

But escape is deprecated and not recommended. Can you please advise how do we fix this ?

Comment: It's weird that it's not allowed because according to [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4), the query string can contain any `pchar`, which also includes `sub-delims`, and `'` is one of them. You could manually encode `'` using `.replace(/'/g, '%27')`. node.js would however by default encode the `'` in the query string if you'd use `URLSearchParams` for it, so it would also work to construct a `URL` object and then getting the path+query from it again: `const url = new URL(path, 'http://dummy'); const encoded = url.path + url.search;`

Comment: If we do .replace(/'/g, '%27') and then apply encodeURIComponent, it works but is that right solution ? What happen when we have some other special characters like double quotes or * ?

Comment: Replacing and then encoding _again_ is wrong. Please see my second example.